# Using UpdateChildValue to Edit from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wanting to update the child values after editing inside the textfields.

At the moment I have this action:

```
@IBAction func updateAction(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let itemNameText = itemName.text, let itemDateText = itemDate.text else { return }

        guard itemNameText.characters.count > 0, itemDateText.characters.count > 0 else {

            print("Complete all fields")
            return
        }
        let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        let key = item.ref!.key
        let itemList = Item(itemName: itemNameText, itemDate: itemDateText, uid: uid!)
        let editItemRef = databaseRef.child("/usersList/\(key)")
        editItemRef.updateChildValues(itemList.toAnyObject())
        print("edited")

    }
```

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKPbyD2PDCs) but he seems to use the username, and as I only have the email or uid (userID) as authentication I thought I'd use the uid.

This is my toAnyObject function inside my class:

```
func toAnyObject() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    return ["itemName": itemName as AnyObject, "itemDate": itemDate as AnyObject, "userID": userID as AnyObject]
}
```

When I run the breakpoint it does show the edited value of the item however the update doesn't appear to be performing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be extra safe, try dropping the *leading* slash from your path:

```
databaseRef.child("usersList/\(key)")
```

…and try printing the `Error` returned by Firebase, if any:

```
editItemRef.updateChildValues(itemList.toAnyObject()) { 
    (error, _) in
    if let error = error { 
        print("ERROR: \(error)")
    } else {
        print("SUCCESS")
    }
```

**Edit**. We found out he was using the wrong database path. The right one is:

```
databaseRef.child("users").child(uid!).child("usersList/‌​\(key)")
```

Comment: Nothing changes still

Comment: Strange but there is no error and it goes through. However nothing changes still.

Comment: Please double check that your code is actually using the expected Firebase app, in case you created more than one (for tests, etc).

Comment: Yes, it appears to be the correct one as I was able to add item

Comment: Ok after several debugging I  fixed it, I was referencing it incorrectly it seems.

Comment: Good! So try using this path instead: "user/\(uid!)/usersList".

Comment: Yeah I did this: databaseRef.child("users").child(uid!).child("/usersList/\(key)")

Comment: Can I update your answer for future reference and others to see? :)

Comment: @mteera I already updated my answer to better reflect our final solution ;-) Feel free to further edit as you see fit…

Comment: Haha thank you still new to this! Thanks very much again for your time :)